# Laravel SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: integer

Tags: php, laravel, database, postgresql, eloquent

I have like this migration file:

```
Schema::create('posts', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->integer('sort_order')->default(0);
    $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
});
```

And I have also seeder:

```
class SeedPostsTable extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $posts = $this->getPosts();

        foreach ($posts as $title => $column) {
            $posts[] = [
              'title' => $title,
              'slug' => Str::slug($title),
            ];
        }

        Post::insert($posts);
        Post::query()->update(['sort_order' => \DB::raw('`id`')]);
    }
}
```

As database driver I use Postgres and when I run this seeder get like this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: `integer`
LINE 1: update "posts" set "sort_order" = `id`
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast. (SQL: update "posts" set "sort_order" = `id`)
```

I can't set `public $incrementing = false;` and `protected $keyType = 'string';` in my model because I need integer data type as ID column.

How I can fix this error?

Comment: How hard can it be to read the documentation that is so well crafted by the community? A simple read shows `integer` alone as a method does not exist... https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#available-column-types

Comment: Nobody says here that the framework documentation is difficult to structure for reading and understanding. It's just that in my case the problem arose when connecting the postgresql database driver after working correctly in mysql. @matiaslauriti

Comment: If the problem would be related to the data type, then I would solve it myself, but the problem is not in this. Seeder runs without any errors in mysql but returns an error in postgresql

Comment: Can you show the raw SQL that's generated by your migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Post::query()->update(['sort_order' => \DB::raw('`id`')]);
```

You should use:

```
Post::query()->update(['sort_order' => \DB::raw('"id"')]);
```

Comment: That would just set sort_order to be "id" as string, and that's clearly not what is asked.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in a mismatch of the data types:

In Laravel `$table->increments('id')` is a big unsigned integer, not an integer. Make `sort_order` the same type:

```php
Schema::create('posts', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('sort_order')->default(0);
    $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
});
```